# Firestore: Get documents by field in their subcollection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a chat app, so I have a Chatrooms and Users. Every chatroom have a subcollection named User List, basicly it's list of user's which are located in this chatroom.
[image]
[image]
I need to show to users only their chatrooms (chats they're participating). For now I made another subcollection in every user document. This collection contains Chatroom documents.

[image]

And this works ok. But I think it can be solved without a usage of additional subcollection of Chatrooms in user documents. Maybe by a query. So I need a query like this:

```
Query chatrooms = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("Chatrooms")
    .document() //Here's the problem, I need to query through every document, not just through specific one
    .collection("User List")
    .whereEqualTo("user_id", userId);
```

Is this any way to do this?

 And another question, is this efficient or maybe I should stay on my previous solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). With that you can query across all `User List` subcollections to find the user documents.

```
db.collectionGroup("User List").whereEqualTo("user_id", userId).get()
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
          for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
             Log.i("User", document.getId());
             Log.i("Chat room", document.getReference().getParent().getParent().getId());
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I've created an index and it worked! Is this any better way to map the results of this query to the list of Chatroom objects? For now I just get IDs of chatrooms from Your example and use another query to get objects. Feels like two queries for this is kinda bad solution.

Comment: Results of a query always come from a single collection type, you can't join across `User List` and `Chatrooms`. So you'll need to get the chat room documents separately. That's the same in both approach, unless you duplicate the data into each user document either under `Chatrooms/$roomId/User List` or under `/Users/$uid/Chatrooms`.